# Stop form submission without in line JavaScript using an external function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to stop form submission without in line JavaScript using an external function, in order to reuse this function.

I do not understand this behavior with onsubmit or addEventListener.

None of the functions works.

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("myForm1").onsubmit = function(){myFunction1()};

    document.getElementById("myForm2").addEventListener("submit", myFunction1);

}

function myFunction3() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

function myFunction2() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    preventDefault();
}

function myFunction1() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm1" action="/action_page.php">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit1">
</form>

<form id="myForm2" action="/action_page.php">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a form is submitted, it will dispatch a `submit` event, which will call any events listening to that event. The events will receive an `Event` object as their first parameter. You need to use this parameter to call `preventDefault()`.

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('myForm1').addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
}
```

In all of your examples, you never get a hold of that event, which is why they all fail.

Answer (score 0):

`Function1` does not specify `event.preventDefault();`

Change that to:

```
function myFunction1() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("myForm1").onsubmit = function(){myFunction1()};

    document.getElementById("myForm2").addEventListener("submit", myFunction1);

}

function myFunction1() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm1" action="/action_page.php">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit1">
</form>

<form id="myForm2" action="/action_page.php">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit2">
</form>
```